# How do I use regex in Java to pull this from html?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to pull data from the ESPN box scores, and one of the html files has:

`<td style="text-align:left" nowrap><a href="http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/2754/channing-frye">Channing Frye</a>, PF</td>`

and I'm only interested in grabbing the name (Channing Frye) and the position (PF)

Right now, I've been using `Pattern.quote(start) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(end)` to grab text in between `start` and `end`, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to grab text that starts with pattern `.../http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/` and then can contain `(any integer)/anyfirst-anylast">` then grab the name I need (Channing Frye), then `</a>,` and then grab the position I need (PF) and ends with pattern `</td>`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this pattern:

```
\\/nba\\/player\\/_\\/.*\\\">(.*)<.+>,\\s(.*)<
```

This will match any link in the html that contains `/nba/player/

```
String re = "\\/nba\\/player\\/_\\/.*\\">(.*)<.+>,\\s(.*)<";
String str = "<td style=\"text-align:left\" nowrap><a href=\"http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/2754/channing-frye\">Channing Frye</a>, PF</td>";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
```

example: http://regex101.com/r/hA3uV0

Answer (score 2):

Here is the pattern:

```
http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/(\d+)/([\w-]+)">(.*?)</a>,\s*(\w+)</td>
```

You can use this tool - http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html for verifying  regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
[A-Z\sa-z0-9]+(?=</a>)|\w+(?=</td>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one regex:

- . is used for any item, .+ is used for any 1+ items
- .* means o or more items
- \s is used for space

  ```
  String str = "<td style=\"text-align:left\" nowrap><a href=\"http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/2754/channing-frye\">Channing Frye</a>, PF</td>";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<td.+>.*<a.+>(.+)</a>[\\s,]+(.+)</td>");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

  while(matcher.find()){
      System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
      System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
String lString = "<td style=\"text-align:left\" nowrap><a href=\"http://espn.go.com/nba/player/_/id/2754/channing-frye\">Channing Frye</a>, PF</td>";
Pattern lPattern = Pattern.compile("<td.+><a.+id/\\d+/.+\\-.+>(.+)</a>, (.+)</td>");
Matcher lMatcher = lPattern.matcher(lString);
while(lMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(lMatcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(lMatcher.group(2));
}
```

This will give you :

```
Channing Frye
PF
```